# Array does not work in GetCompetitivePricingForASINSample Amazon MWS PHP

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I want to request from a text file with the ASINS (1 AINS in 1 Line). But I always get an error. The file has no more than 20 ASINs.
 I get error

> "Warning: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\MarketplaceWebServiceProducts\Client.php on line
>   1405
>   or
>
> Caught Exception: parameter ASINList.ASIN.1 failed a validation check:
>   Extraneous whitespace for input value: " " Response Status Code: 400
>   Error Code: InvalidRequest Error Type

```
$arr = file("asin.txt"); 
    $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest();
    $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
    $request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
    $asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
    $asin_list->setASIN(array($arr));

    $request->setASINList($asin_list);
```

If I write so, does not work.

```
$asin_list->setASIN(array($arr[0],$arr[1]));
```

If I write so, then works

```
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
$asin_list->setASIN(array('0470165057' ,'3944660110'
,'3000383964' ,'3000567852'....
```

How do I make a request from a file with a list (1 request 20 ASINs) from the file with 1000 ASINS?

Please help me.
And apologies for my english

PS.
Result from Asin.txt with print_r

> Array ( [0] => 3944660110 [1] => 3000383964 [2] => 3000400567 [3] =>
>   3000449523 [4] => 3000489169 [5] => 3000518290 [6] => 3000539069 )

asin.txt - 1 Line 1 ASIN

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);

$arr = file('asin.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$arr_chunks = array_chunk($arr, 20, TRUE);

$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();

//$asin_list->setASIN($arr_chunks[0]);
//$request->setASINList($asin_list);

 If $ asin_list-> setASIN ($ arr_chunks [0]);  - Works
 If $ asin_list-> setASIN ($ arr_chunks [1]); - Dont Work
```

Comment: `$asin_list->setASIN($arr);` should work, assuming the file has less than 20 lines (it has 7 in your example as dumped with print_r) and that all elements are strings, and not integers (print_r does not reveal that, var_dump would).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use array_chunk() to divide your 1000 asins into group of 20s e.g.

```
$asins_chunks = array_chunk($asins_array, 20, TRUE);
```

I use this code and it works:

```
$service = new
 MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client($this->aws_access_key,
 $this->aws_secret_access_key, $this->application_name,
 $this->application_version, $this->config);

 $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest();
 $request->setSellerId($this->seller_id);
 $request->setMarketplaceId($this->marketplace_id);

 //requesting product's data for "New" products
 $request->setItemCondition("New");

 //excluding our price data in product api response
 $request->setExcludeMe(TRUE);

 $asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();

 //creating $iec_asins array for returning price data back
 $asins = array("ASIN1","ASIN2","ASIN3");

 $asin_list->setASIN($asins);
 $request->setASINList($asin_list);
```